# vaadin - "Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null"

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, vaadin, lookup

My vaadin v24 project is running fine on test mode. The deployed WAR is not starting on Tomcat.

The following error is reported:

**"Cannot invoke 'com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)' because 'lookup' is null"**

I am implementing login security with JPA.
I have found nothing relevant online about this issue.

How can this be fixed?

The security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/";
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/images/*.png").permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);
    }
}
```

the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.tools.dimcontrol.data.repository")
@Theme(value = "dimcontrol")

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                               SqlInitializationProperties properties, UserRepository repository) {
        // This bean ensures the database is only initialized when empty
        return new SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(dataSource, properties) {
            @Override
            public boolean initializeDatabase() {
                if (repository.count() == 0L) {
                    return super.initializeDatabase();
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/d6e40e84-c292-43aa-a0a7-44ff9774bd1f -->
    <groupId>com.tools.dimcontrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>dimcontrol</artifactId>
    <name>dimcontrol</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.0.2</vaadin.version>
        <selenium.version>4.8.1</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <!--<version>8.0.32</version>-->
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <!--<version>3.0.5</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <!--<version>2.1.1</version>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5464</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev-server</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

and the Tomcat error log:

```
...
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.019 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [E:\webapps\dimcontrol.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/dimcontrol]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'VaadinSecurityFilterChainBean' defined in class path resource [com/tools/dimcontrol/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'VaadinSecurityFilterChainBean' defined in class path resource [com/tools/dimcontrol/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:810)
        ... 61 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 77 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.RouteUtil.resolve(RouteUtil.java:283)
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.RouteUtil.getRoutePath(RouteUtil.java:110)
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.VaadinWebSecurity.setLoginView(VaadinWebSecurity.java:426)
        at com.tools.dimcontrol.security.SecurityConfiguration.configure(SecurityConfiguration.java:39)
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.VaadinWebSecurity.filterChain(VaadinWebSecurity.java:140)
        at com.tools.dimcontrol.security.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$filterChain$3(<generated>)
        at com.tools.dimcontrol.security.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$1.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at com.tools.dimcontrol.security.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.filterChain(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        ... 78 more
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.032 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [E:\webapps\dimcontrol.war] has finished in [13,753] ms
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.032 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\webapps\docs]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\webapps\docs] has finished in [62] ms
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\webapps\examples]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.375 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\webapps\examples] has finished in [281] ms
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.375 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\webapps\host-manager]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.407 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [32] ms
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.407 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\webapps\manager]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\webapps\manager] has finished in [31] ms
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\webapps\ROOT]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [15] ms
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.453 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.485 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [14287] milliseconds
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.485 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.485 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.517 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.533 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.533 WARNING [Thread-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [dimcontrol] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
30-Mar-2023 17:27:41.533 WARNING [Thread-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [dimcontrol] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:91)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: [That class](https://origin.vaadin.com/api/platform/current/com/vaadin/flow/di/Lookup.html) seems be a [Service Provider Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface). An SPI is used to locate implementations of a desired service at runtime. So this must be a core class within the Vaadin Flow framework. I doubt you've provided enough details for anyone to debug. Did you just create a new project? Did that project ever run successfully? If so, backtrack to when things when wrong.

Comment: Yes, it always worked fine in IntelliJ/development mode. I have started the project using an export from https://start.vaadin.com/ with the login security enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, the deployed WAR never worked in Tomcat. I guess some security config is still missing. If I remove the "setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);", the WAR is loaded.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The linked question is a generic question about NPEs, while this question is about a specific framework-internal dependency not being present.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
Just upgrade to Vaadin 24.1.1 and Spring Boot 3.1.1 solved the problem